# Take time in microseconds between two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer, local-storage

Hi I have tried different solutions but I can't find what I'm looking for, what I want to do is to take the time in microseconds between two functions. But the problem is first that I need to start the timer right after a css animation has finished, second I need to stop the timer when someone presses either B or R on the keyboard, and third I need to send the time from the timer with the information about which key that was pressed. Here's a code to show what I mean, first one is to call the timer in css:

```
#first-child {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: white;
   border-radius: 100%;
   margin-top: 150px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 550px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
   -moz-animation: myfirst 1s;
   animation: myfirst 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
   0% {background: white;}
  20% {background: white;}
  40% {background: white;}
  60% {background: white;}
  80% {background: white;}
 100% {background: red;}
}
@keyframes myfirst {
   0% {background: white;}
  20% {background: white;}
  40% {background: white;}
  60% {background: white;}
  80% {background: white;}
 100% {background: red;}
}

//Call the timer here
```

And the second is to stop the timer onkeypress:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode,
   character = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

   //Stop timer here

   var answer;
   if(e.charCode == 98 || e.keyCode == 98) {
      answer = "B";
   //Or Stop timer here

   } else if(e.charCode == 114 || e.keyCode == 114) {
      answer = "R";
   //Or stop timer here

   } else {
      alert("Press B or R to continue");
      return false;
```

And the third is to send the time with the other information:

```
localStorage.setItem("keypressed", "");
localStorage.setItem("keypressed", "<h3>Test 1</h3>Your Answer: " + answer + "<br />Correct Answer: R<hr>");

//Send the time here

window.location.href="Take time in milliseconds and send it 1.html";
return true;
```

I thought that maybe if you can take the time and save it in the local storage and send it with the other information. But I don't know how, I'm working on a reaction test and I have 50 different files and one result file. So I'm just going to post two of the test files and the result file so you know what I mean.

Test1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test1</title>
<style>
body {
   overflow: hidden;
}
#first-child {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: white;
   border-radius: 100%;
   margin-top: 150px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 550px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
   -moz-animation: myfirst 1s;
   animation: myfirst 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
        0% {background: white;}
       20% {background: white;}
       40% {background: white;}
       60% {background: white;}
       80% {background: white;}
      100% {background: red;}
}
@keyframes myfirst {
        0% {background: white;}
       20% {background: white;}
       40% {background: white;}
       60% {background: white;}
       80% {background: white;}
      100% {background: red;}
}
#first-parent {
   color: blue;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 600px;
   margin-right: 0px;
}
#second-parent {
   color: red;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 40px;
   margin-right: 0px;
}
p {
   margin-left: 640px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="first-child"></div>

<div>
<button id="first-parent">B</button>
<button id="second-parent">R</button>
</div>

<br />
<p>1/50</p>

<script>
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode,
   character = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

   var answer;
   if(e.charCode == 98 || e.keyCode == 98) {
      answer = "B";
   } else if(e.charCode == 114 || e.keyCode == 114) {
      answer = "R";
   } else {
      alert("Press B or R to continue");
      return false;
   }

   localStorage.setItem("keypressed", "");
   localStorage.setItem("keypressed", "<h3>Test 1</h3>Your Answer: " + answer + "<br /> Correct Answer: R<hr>");
   window.location.href="Take time in milliseconds and send it 1.html";
   return true;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Test2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test2</title>
<style>
body {
   overflow: hidden;
}
#first-child {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: white;
   border-radius: 0%;
   margin-top: 150px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 550px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
   -moz-animation: myfirst 1s;
   animation: myfirst 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
        0% {background: white;}
       20% {background: white;}
       40% {background: white;}
       60% {background: white;}
       80% {background: white;}
      100% {background: blue;}
}
@keyframes myfirst {
        0% {background: white;}
       20% {background: white;}
       40% {background: white;}
       60% {background: white;}
       80% {background: white;}
      100% {background: blue;}
}
#first-parent {
   color: blue;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 600px;
   margin-right: 0px;
}
#second-parent {
   color: red;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 40px;
   margin-right: 0px;
}
p {
   margin-left: 640px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="first-child"></div>

<div>
<button id="first-parent">B</button>
<button id="second-parent">R</button>
</div>

<br />
<p>2/50</p>

<script>
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode,
   character = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

   var answer;
   if(e.charCode == 98 || e.keyCode == 98) {
      answer = "B";
   } else if(e.charCode == 114 || e.keyCode == 114) {
      answer = "R";
   } else {
      alert("Press B or R to continue");
      return false;
   }

   var res = localStorage.getItem("keypressed");
   res+= "<h3>Test 2</h3>Your Answer: " + answer + "<br /> Correct Answer: B<hr>";
   localStorage.setItem("keypressed", res);
   window.location.href="Take time in milliseconds and send it 2.html";
   return true;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Result</title>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="result"></div>
<script>
var result = localStorage.getItem("keypressed");
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So then again I need to take time in microseconds between two different functions and then send it to the result page, I know HTML, JavaScript and jQuery so no PHP solutions and if there's any questions just ask, peace !

**UPDATE** I really need some help with this, I have been searching everywhere but I can't find anything ! Any idea someone ?

Comment: This should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796936/how-do-you-detect-when-css-animations-start-and-end-with-javascript

Comment: Yeah it helped but I still need to know how to start the timer ? If there is any command or something ? :p

Comment: Try searching. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313893/how-to-measure-time-taken-by-a-function-to-execute

Comment: Can you help me combining these two with the keypress ?

Comment: @levi would you mind ?